# Error in terminal emulator: Alacritty

Tags: arch-linux, kde, fish

I installed [Garuda Linux](https://garudalinux.org/) today. The default shell emulator is [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) and the default shell, [fish](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell). However, after the update to the system, its constantly giving a warning:
`Config error: shell: data did not match any variant of untagged enum Program`

[image: error]

What is this error and what is causing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the latest update of alacritty. The issue is still unknown as of today (1st Jan 2021). However, to fix the problem, you simply have to [roll-back](https://gitlab.com/garuda-linux/themes-and-settings/settings/garuda-dr460nized/-/commit/72718ddfddd573edd28e66413dcaecb7ce63e2d7) the alacritty config file located at `~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml`.